# For what is a general allow ACK rule in iptables good for?

Tags: iptables

I've encountered some iptables configuration with incoming rules starting with a rule that allows all TCP packets with ACK flag, followed by all the obvius service port rules. Why is that? The server still responds with this rule disabled. Is there a useful acceptance of ACK for other ports then the served services ones?

Comment: Do you have an example of such a rule?

Comment: Yes, for example: 
`-P INPUT DROP`
`-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ACK ACK`
followed by the usual service-port matching rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The person that engineered the firewall is probably the best person to answer the `why is this here?` question.

If I take a stab at finding a useful use case:

**Premise:** TCP packets with the ACK flag are *common*

**Premise:** Will stop evaluating at the matching first `ACCEPT, DROP, REJECT, etc..` rule

**Assumption:** ACK packets are largely harmless

```
#Accept any TCP Acknowlegements and let the OS / Service handle any issues
-A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
...
...
-A INPUT -j DROP
```

**Conclusion:** The ACK statements may have been added to increase Firewall performance.

I don't have any benchmarking to back up such an assumption.

Comment: Well, the engeneer is possible 'seen that somewhere in the internet' in this case I guess. However, your explanation give me the feeling that there is no magic effects in this and this is simply for performance as you said, or maybe a relic.

Comment: @dronus That "ACK packets are largely harmless" isn't really a valid assumption. This creates a hole in the firewall big enough to portscan through; nmap even has a flag to do an ACK scan which this rule will permit.

Comment: So the config done that way out of what reason whatever, is flawed and should not be used?

Comment: It is not inherently 'flawed'. It depends on the use case. If performance is a higher priority than security, it may have merits. If security is important, it has flaws. The world will never be black and white.